# How to group or subset a data frame by two conditions in R

Tags: r, group-by, subset

I need to create subsets or groups of my data based on two different conditions. This is a sample of how the data is structured:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "d", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
               kpi = c ("rev", "rev", "rev", "rev", "rev", "fte", "fte", "fte", "fte", "fte"),
               value = c(100, 150, 200, 50, 70, 3, 5, 8, 9, 3))

       id kpi value
    1   a rev   100
    2   a rev   150
    3   a rev   200
    4   b rev    50
    5   d rev    70
    6   b fte     3
    7   b fte     5
    8   c fte     8
    9   d fte     9
    10  e fte     3
```

- the first column is filled with IDs for companies. There can be multiple rows for each ID as they might have data for multiple months (months column not included in the sample data) and data for both rev (Revenue) and fte (Full Time Equivalent)
- I want to select every company for which the fte average in a certain range: 1-5

  - for example company b should be included as it has an average fte of 4 (in one month 3 in another 5), company d should be excluded as it has a higher fte.
- for those included I want all rows to remain in the data frame, therefore also those rows with rev data. The goal is to calculate an average revenue for cohorts of companies with specific fte numbers.

The new.data frame with the mentioned conditions should look like this for the sample data:

```
 df <- data.frame(id = c("b", "b", "b", "e"),
               kpi = c("rev", "fte", "fte", "fte"), value = c(50, 3, 5, 3))

      id kpi value
    1  b rev    50
    2  b fte     3
    3  b fte     5
    4  e fte     3
```

It would be applied to a data.frame of about 40,000 rows.

I already did some research and found a lot on creating subsets with multiple conditions but nothing I could apply to my specific problem. I am sorry if this an obvious question, I am a R rookie and could really use some help!

If I didn't specify the problem clear enough feel free to ask and I will try to explain it more clearly!

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why is row 4 included if you want the average (50) between 1 and 5?

Comment: Row 4 is not needed you are right, for the ongoing calculation it does not matter if it is included. I thought maybe it would be easier to code if it is left in the df but I might be completely off with that. So: both works for me leaving it in the data frame or excluding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group on id and then filter those satisfying the condition:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(between(mean(value[kpi == "fte"]), 1, 5)) %>%
   ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id    kpi   value
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 b     rev     50.
2 b     fte      3.
3 b     fte      5.
4 e     fte      3.
```

Comment: plus 1, this is by far more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(id,kpi) %>% 
  mutate(Mean=mean(value)) %>% 
  mutate(gr= between(Mean, 1, 5)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(gr2 = ifelse(any(gr) & kpi == "rev",T, F)) %>% 
  filter(gr | gr2) %>% 
  select(1:3)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
  id    kpi   value
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 b     rev     50.
2 b     fte      3.
3 b     fte      5.
4 e     fte      3.
```

I included each step to illustrate what the idea is.

1. First calculate the mean for each `id` and `kpi` values.
2. Add `TRUE` if the mean  is between 1 and 5
3. group by id again to filter the corresponding `rev` values
4. filter
5. select the right columns.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use `ave` to create a temporary variable and then use that variable.

```
a <- ave(df$value, df$id, df$kpi, FUN = mean)
new <- df[1 <= a & a <= 5, ]
new
#   id kpi value
#6   b fte     3
#7   b fte     5
#10  e fte     3
```

Now remove what you no longer need.

```
rm(a)    # clean up
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df)
df[df[kpi=="fte", if (between(mean(value), 1, 5)) id, id], on="id"][, -c("V1")]
# > df[df[kpi=="fte", if (between(mean(value), 1, 5)) id, id], on="id"][, -c("V1")]
#    id kpi value
# 1:  b rev    50
# 2:  b fte     3
# 3:  b fte     5
# 4:  e fte     3
```

or

```
df[df[kpi=="fte", if (between(mean(value), 1, 5)) id, id][,-2], on="id"][]
```